# RTX Recursive Rendering

Tags: unity-game-engine, raytracing, rtx

I am trying to achieve nice looking reflections with the unity RTX capabilities. Under the volume component, I have turned on recursive rendering:

[image]

I then set my material's rendering pass to be raytracing. The setting only allows for a ray length of 50 and I appear to get weird artefacts:

[image]
[image]

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? What is that weird line and how do I blend it? How do I get rid of the black when an intersection exceeds the ray's length of 50 units?

Cheers!

Comment: I'm not a Unity user, but sometimes you can enter a bigger number in the text box than the slider allows.

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue, I found a fix. It has to do with the light cluster: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@7.1/manual/Ray-Tracing-Light-Cluster.html